# PXE boot install an OS and getting its successfull OS install status using a program

Tags: java

So, here's my case, I have a machine(say M) to be booted using PXE boot and install an OS (say CentOS) in that machine. M will not have any monitors or keyboards attached to it.

PXE boot server is also running from a CentOS machine (say B)

How will I write a program (bash script, Java program) that sits in the machine B and get the status/notification that machine M has successfully finished installing the OS.

Note, that I cannot check manually that the OS has finished the installation. I need to automate that process.

I will be glad if you guys could suggest the best and the efficient way of doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple enough way would be to use NFS to access a directory on B from M after installation has completed (depending on the installation method -- for kickstart, use a post-install script).  Create a file in some directory as a flag that the installation has completed.  On machine 'B', you can use `inotify` features to detect the completion (either `inotifywait` from a shell script or `libinotify` otherwise).

If NFS is barred for some reason, you should be able to use `scp` or `sshfs` fairly easily.  The most complex part is copying over the generated keys.

Comment: Brian: Any other ways without NFS? It's ok if it's hard...

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to get the server to talk to a webserver/web service to say the install is finished, and pass values to identify which machine it is.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem recently with the debian PXE installer.

I set my hosts to boot from the network.  I send a POST request with the system-uuid 
of the machine to identify it and tell the server it needs installing.  When the server 
receives this request, it creates a specific pxelinux.cfg file with then uuid as a filename, making sure that the specific host gets the debian install with the special parameters.

I have a preseed file that is a template and it is rendered specific to each machine.  During the debian install, there is a chance to run a late command, which I use to download a script from the server and execute it in the target environment.  This script sends another POST request informing the server that stage one of the installation is complete, and also installing the script for the second install stage.  The server then deletes the specific pxeconfig file.  The default pxeconfig file will default to booting from the hard drive in ten seconds, so when the host boots from the network again, it defaults to booting from the hard drive and the install continues.

You can look at the code here:  https://github.com/umeboshi2/paella